# elasticsearch search phase execution

Tags: exception, search, elasticsearch, execution, phase

I'm having issues and I don't know where to turn.  Long story short, my web designer left me high and dry and I have no idea what he did and he refuses to answer his phone. I have access to the main page but after that, I'm completely locked out and staring at a SearchPhaseExecutionException for every single product in my store.  Any help would be much appreciated as I am completely clueless on what to do.  Here is the full error log and I can post any additional information as is necessary to troubleshoot this problem:

```
 SearchPhaseExecutionException at /category/1
Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[_na_][product][0]: No     active shards}{[_na_][product][1]: No active shards}{[_na_][product][2]: No active shards}{[_na_][product][3]: No active shards}{[_na_][product][4]: No active shards}
```

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere on your web site/farm you have an elasticsearch server running. This server has an index called `product`, and I would guess this index contains information about products in your store. Currently, this elasticsearch server is experiencing some sort of an issue that made the index unavailable. It might be possible to tell you what is going on by looking at the log file of the elasticsearch server, which is different from the log file of your web server. Do you see any log files called `elasticsearch.log`?

By the way, since it might take several iterations to figure out what's going on, it might be easier to move this conversation to [elasticsearch mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/elasticsearch) or #elasticsearch IRC channel on freenode.

Comment: I've created a discussion on the mailing list at the following link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/elasticsearch/cjEP0FmZxnE

As for the log files, I have plenty of them but the most recent one goes a little something like this: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/408199/elasticsearch.log

Comment: Could you post the latest elasticsearch log somewhere where I don't have to type my email address in order to get the link?

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, I'm still kinda scatterbrained with this issue
http://www.filedropper.com/elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

some times this error happened because of the data, data to be searched has to be cleaned as elasticSearch will crash with some words like " [PREPARATION " or even " word: "  as punctuations drive it crazy.

if you don't want to clean the data you can just catch the exception and it will continue